# Recurrence in ID3 algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, decision-tree, recurrence

```
import numpy as np


training_set = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

def p(X):
   Fx = X[:,X.shape[1]-1]
   x0= 0
   x1= 0
   for i in range(len(Fx)):
       if Fx[i-1] == 1:
           x0 = x0+1
       else:
           x1 = x1+1
   P0 = x0/len(Fx)
   P1 = x1/len(Fx)      
   return(P0,P1)    

def H(X):
    result = -p(X)[0]*np.log(p(X)[0])-p(X)[1]*np.log(p(X)[1]) #needs to be log2
    print("1 = pure, 0 = unpure 1/2 = decision can be random:  Calculating Entropy: -" + str(p(X)[0]) + "*" + str(np.log(p(X)[0])) + "-" + str(p(X)[1]) + "*" + str(np.log(p(X)[1])) )
    return result

def Q(X,i):
    Xi = X[:,i]
    result0= 0
    result1= 0
    for j in range(len(Xi)):
        if Xi[j] == 1:
            result1 = result1 + len(X[i,:])
        else: result0 = result0 + len(X[i,:])
    result1 = result1/len(X)
    result0 = result0/len(X)
    return(result0,result1) 

def X_column(X,i,v):
    list = X[np.where(X[:,i] == v)]
    return list

def IG(X,i):
    result = H(X)-Q(X,i)[0]*H(X_column(X,i,0))-Q(X,i)[1]*H(X_column(X,i,1))
    return result

#To teach decision trees on learning set S, we will used following algorithm(ID3):
#    1. There is example set S
#    2. If |{f(x) : (x, f(x)) ∈ S}| = 1= 1 create leaf with label f(x)
#    3. For i = 1,2,...,n calculate value IG(S,i)
#    4. May j be an index o fthe biggest of calculated values
#    5. Set node with label Xj
#    6. For subsets:
#        S0 = {(x, f(x)) ∈ S : xj = 0}
#        and
#        S1 = {(x, f(x)) ∈ S : xj = 1}
#        run algorithm recurrent (for S ← S0 i S ← S1) and add new nodes as a childs for a node with label j

def ID3(S, recursion = 0, label = 0, tree = np.array()):
    result = np.array()
    recursion += 1
    rows = S.shape[0]
    columns = S.shape[1]      
    if S[:,columns-1] == True:
        tree[recursion]= S[0,columns-1]
        break    
    for i in range(rows):
        result[i]= IG(S,i)
    j = result.max()
    tree[recursion]= 1 #czym jest etykieta xj
    S0 = X_column(S,i,0)
    tree[recursion+1] = ID3(S0,recursion = recursion )
    S1 = X_column(S,i,1)
    tree[recursion+2] = ID3(S1,recursion = recursion)
    return tree

def pruning():
    return tree
```

I have been working on implementing ID3 algorithm(decision tree), but I have no idea how to solve the recurrence. I've also translated algorithm steps from my laboratory list. Most of the necessary functions are already written, but I just can't grasp recurrency concept at that advanced level. And most of the tutorials are very trivial.